# devising an ActiveStorage validation based on a class attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a multi-tenant application,

```
class Picture 
  has_one_attached :file
  belongs_to  :picture_validation
```

Validations, for example, on the size of the upload and employing the [active_storage_validations](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations) gem needs to

```
validates :file, attached: true, size: { less_than: XXX.megabytes , message: t('is too large') }
```

given the multiple tenant facet of the application, a

```
class PictureValidation
  belongs_to :shop
```

(the tenant being shop_id) and has a generated column `size_less_than:integer`

The tenancy is stored in `session[:shop_id]` and would be accessible for controller actions. However, this being the model definition, on a create action, the object is inexistent and thus `self.shop_id` is not invocable.

How can this validation be determined based on the PictureValidation table attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gem appears to have a novel feature which [lets the options be passed as procs](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations/blob/master/lib/active_storage_validations/option_proc_unfolding.rb).

The readme has this example:

```
validates :proc_files, limit: { max: -> (record) { record.admin? ? 100 : 10 } }
```

So if the model is built off the parent record and thus has it's `shop_id` set we can interpolate that you should be able to do something like:

```
validates :file, 
  attached: true, 
  size: { 
   less_than: ->(record){ record.shop.size_less_than }, 
   message: t('is too large') 
  }
```